# With CUPS installed on Linux Machine,Do i need to install Drivers for Printers for All Printers Available on Network?

Tags: linux, cups

With CUPS installed on Linux Machine, do I need to install drivers for printers  for all printers available on network?

I want to use CUPS utility, so do I need to install drivers for all printers? e.g Brother, Canon

Comment: Are you using cups on client or on server (or both) and for which are you installing the drivers?

Comment: i want to use CUPS Client & server on same Device.My question is the drivers are required ?

Answer (score 1):

Whether you need to install device specific drivers on your clients depends on how your CUPS server is configured.

If you use *RAW queue* for the printer, you need to install the driver on the client.

If you use a driver with CUPS, RAW queue (or generic PostScript driver) works on client.

Comment: with only having CUPS installed can i print ?